# Spark Sql how to mock current_timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, junit, apache-spark-sql, mockito

I am trying to write unit tests for SparkSql involving current_timestamp.
Each time the test is executed it evaluates the time, so time does't match to the time in the assertion.

this is the method I want to test:

```
protected Dataset<Row> convertInput(Dataset<Row> inputData){
    return sparkSession.sql("select a+1, b+2, current_timestamp as updated_at");
}
```

And I would like to test the method as follows:

```
@Test
public void testConvertInput() {
         Dataset<Row> input = fromJson("test1_input.json");
         Dataset<Row> expected = fromJson("test1_output.json");

         Dataset<Row> output = convertInput(input);
         DatasetAssert.assertSets(expected, output);       
}
```

The assertion fails because of the timestamp comparison.

I tried to add an `current_timestamp` column to the input Dataset, but it doesn't cover all my use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding a column named `current_timestamp`

```
@Test
public void testConvertInput() {
     Timestamp mockTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.parse("2020-01-10T12:00:00.000Z"));
     Dataset<Row> input = fromJson("test1_input.json").withColumn("current_timestamp", lit(mockTime));
     Dataset<Row> expected = fromJson("test1_output.json");

     Dataset<Row> output = convertInput(input);
     DatasetAssert.assertSets(expected, output);       
}
```